# No command executes when i deleted /lib64

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory

I executed command `rm -rf *` when i was in `lib64` or a directory inside it.

(Through comments/answers problem is that i deleted `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` and i don't have a temporary one inside `/var/lib64`)

(I have busybox )

Then I can't execute most of bash commands like `ls`,`bash`. When i try to execute them i see:

```
bash: /usr/bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

or

```
bash: /usr/bin/ls: No such file or directory
```

But a number of commands work properly like `echo`, `cd`

And a number of commands work but not properly like `which` that show the below error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/which: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

When I go to `/usr/bin` through `cd` and then execute command `cd $file` it throw an error. for example, when i execute `cd /usr/bin/ls` it show me:

```
bash: cd: /usr/bin/ls: Not a directory
```

or

```
bash: cd: /usr/bin/bash: Not a directory
```

when i executed 'cd /usr/bin/bash'

and when i open the terminal i show the below message:

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
Failed to execute child process “/bin/bash” (No such file or directory)
```

(With two option: Preferences, Relaunch)

My `$PATH` is `/home/$me/.sdkman/candidates/springboot/current/bin:/home/$me/.cargo/bin:/home/$me/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/grade/gradle-7.0.2/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.8.1/bin:/home/$me/v8/depot_tools:/home/$me/.config/composer/vendor/bin` 
I can use browser, or/and programs previously launched. But i can't launch them again.

I have one open terminal tab with a number of commands previously mentioned and a browser and a document reader. They work but they can't be launched again.

What is can't understand is the below error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/which: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; but you'll need to restore that directory from your backups.  If you delete a file that is already open; the existing running program can still read the contents (as inodes are not freed until nothing is using them - Ubuntu or GNU/Linux is a multi-user OS), but programs that need those libraries won't have them available as they were deleted, thus cannot execute. On reboot (or logout you'll see more effects) you'll see the full effect of your command.  You could also re-install if you don't have backups.

Comment: You probably deleted `ld-linux.so`, which is needed for any dynamically linked executable to run.

Comment: @muru don't you think [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/123353/495805)[And this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123358/495805) solves this issue

Comment: @muru @algnis exactly I deleted that file. but no temporary ld-linux file is in `/var/lib64` directory. better: my `var` directory has not `lib64` directory inside.

Comment: `/usr/bin/busybox ash` (you need to supply full path) should give you a working prompt.  now, you should be able to re-create your missing link `ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.33.so ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` pay attention to the ld-linux version.

Comment: you can do the same from the grub menu, `e` edit any of the menu entries, append `break` to the *linux* line and *ctrl+x*, this should bring a `(initramfs)` prompt, you can then mount your root partition, something like `mount /dev/sda1 /root`, `cd /root/lib64`, this time you need to use a relative path `ln -sf ../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.33.so ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

Comment: Other distributions provide a statically linked `sln` for such emergencies, but not on Ubuntu Server 22.04.

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/bin/which` is a shellscript:

```
~$ cat /usr/bin/which
#! /bin/sh
set -ef

if test -n "$KSH_VERSION"; then
        puts() {
                print -r -- "$*"
        }
else
        puts() {
                printf '%s\n' "$*"
        }
fi
...
...
...
```

This are just the first lines of the script, it is much longer. But we just need to take a look at the very first line which is

```
#! /bin/sh
```

`/bin` is symlinked to `/usr/bin`, so `/bin/sh` points to `/usr/bin/sh`.

Seems you deleted essential systemfiles, that's why commands not work for you.
`cd` and `echo` are not commands but shell-builtins, that's why they still work.

We can't tell you which files you removed since we don't know in which directory you issued the `rm -rf *`-command. Maybe it is possible to copy the files from a live-session and get the system back to work but you'll have to find out yourself which files are missing. Otherwise reinstall.

Hint: On my system I have only a single file in `/lib64`:

```
~$ ~$ ~$ ls -la /lib64/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 13 03:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Oct 13 03:37 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   42 Sep 28 08:38 ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

This is a symlink, just recreating the symlink should be enough, but since commands don't work anymore, you'll have to do this from a live-session.

Comment: You should try `ls -la /lib64/`, since it looks like OP entered the directory before deleting everything in it.

Comment: @muru I don't see any difference between `ls -la /lib64` and `ls -la /lib64/`.

Comment: That is rather strange. The second option should list the contents of the target directory of the symlink (the contents that OP in this case has removed). `ls -laH /lib64/`, then if your `ls` might be an alias that has an option breaking that behaviour.

Comment: @muru Yes, I see this now, you are right. Because `/lib64` is not a folder but a symlink... edited...

Answer (score 1):

On my ubuntu 20.04 system the /lib64/ directory only contains one symlink:

```
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
```

If you accidentally delete that, almost all commands will fail with the following error:

```
# ls -al
-bash: /bin/ls: No such file or directory
```

You can restore the symlink using the following command:

```
cd /lib64/
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so /bin/ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The /lib64 directory contains shared libraries as well as the ld-linux interpreter that are needed for nearly all executables.  These share common code in shared libraries rather than copying it into each executable.  Things like shell scripts would probably also not work, as those run commands that may be broken, and need an interpreter (like bash) that may also be broken.

The commands that work are either built into your shell (like `cd` and `echo`) or are statically linked.  The busybox command is by design statically linked and has abbreviated versions of many commands built into it.

Damage to system directories like /lib64 are near fatal to a unix system.  To restore functionality, you need to restore the missing files.  Options to do this would include:

- restore from backup
- reinstalling the deb files they came from
- copying the files from another identical system with the same version of the operating system
- boot from a live install disk and use tools on the live disk to replace the missing files
- completely reinstall the operating system (back up data first)

It may be possible to do a partial restore and then use something like `dpkg -V` to get a list of things that are different or missing from the stock files and reinstall some of the damaged packages with `apt install --reinstall`.  Unfortunately, dpkg and the tools it uses all rely on shared libraries, so at least the critical ones have to be there before this helps.

Sadly, in situations like this, it is frequently faster and easier to reinstall from scratch than repair the damage.